# How to pick first occurence of a field and last occurence of another field at the same time in a SAS dataset?

Tags: sql, sas

I have a SAS data set (grouped by ID, Sub_ID Ordered By ID) say as follows,

```
ID        Sub_ID      Field_1         Field_2
1            4           4               8
1            5           9               5A
```

Desired Output (No Sub_ID required in Output Dataset):

```
ID        Field_1         Field_2
1            4               5A
```

What I want to do?

I need a single row output for each ID where value of Field_1 should be same as it was for the first occurence of that particular ID, while Field_2 should be same as it was for the last occurence of the particular ID.

If I use First.ID, output is

```
ID        Field_1         Field_2
1            4               8
```

And if I use Last.ID, output is

```
ID        Field_1         Field_2
1            9               5A
```

I am not sure how to combine these two conditions.

Comment: How do we know wich occurence is the *first* or *last* ?

Comment: @GMB Added an extra field for better understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is store the first value in a new variable (using a `retain` statement to copy it across rows), then output when you reach the last value per ID.
The following code will do just that, based on the current sort order of the data.  I assume your real data has an extra variable that will allow proper sorting of the data.

```
data have;
input ID Field_1 Field_2 $;
datalines;
1 4 8
1 9 5A
;
run;

data want;
set have;
by id;
retain field_1_1st;
if first.id then field_1_1st = field_1;
if last.id then do;
    field_2_last = field_2;
    output;
    end;
drop field_1 field_2;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

@longfish answer is perfect and this is just another way done in SQL.

```
data have;
input ID        Field_1         Field_2 $;
datalines;
 1            4               8
 1            5               9
 1            9               5A
 ;


  data have_1/view=have_1;
  set have;
  val =_n_;
  run;

   proc sql;
    create table want as 
   select id, field_1,
 max(case when Field_2 =(select field_2 from have_1
                group by id having val=max(val))
      then field_2 end) as field_2
 from have_1
group by id
having val=min(val);
```

[image]

Comment: 'having val=max(val)' this is invalid. Also occurrences for ID does not depend on Min or Max values of Field_1 or Field_2. It depends on value of Sub_ID, so selecting min(Field_1) is wrong.

Comment: good points. proc sql allows certain flexibility unlike any other dbms, hence having val=max(val) is allowed. i have modified a query by a line This queries are based of _ n _ which assigns row numbers in earlier step  and then picking low and high row number.  min on field1 is not required but does no harm  as it picks up the first row  by virtue of val=min(val). In case statement. max or min on field2 is needed because case statement returns 3 rows with high row number and missing values . summary function makes sure that it returns a non missing value.

Comment: Reason for case statement returning null values because it has no else statement and any other values  than val=max(val) will return null values. if you have SAS studio handy, you can try this out with various example. Hope I am clear in comments above, please feel free to comment, if it is unclear.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another data-step solution, using a DOW-loop rather than retain:

```
data have;
input ID Field_1 Field_2 $;
datalines;
1 4 8
1 9 5A
;
run;

data want;
do until(last.id);
  set have;
  by id;
  if first.id then field_1_1st = field_1;
end;
field_1 = field_1_1st;
drop field_1_1st;
run;
```

This loads every row in turn but only outputs the last row per id, so you don't have to handle that one as a special case.

N.B. this will only work if your input dataset does **not** contain a field called `field_1_1st`. If it does, the value from the first row per id won't be carried forward.